# Activating Dragon Naturally Speaking Full-Text Control feature in a WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, speech-recognition, naturallyspeaking

This might be a long shot, but Nuance support redirected to Microsoft so I thought i would try my luck here also.

A bit of context:
I'm trying to use Dragon Naturally Speaking with my WPF application.

They have a feature called "Full-Text Control" that allows you to correct, replace text etc... with voice commands.

Dragon comes with a toolbar that hovers at the top of the screen. Inside that bar, there's a Checkmark icon that turns green when the current focused RichTextBox supports "Full-Text Control"

This feature isn't working with WPF and I'm using a RichTextBox like I'm supposed to.

If i use WinForms, everything works fine.

Has anyone encountered this?
Can I implement something so my RichTextBox/application supports FTC?
How does Dragon evaluate if a RichTextBox/application supports FTC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I was finally able to figure out how to activate FTC for my WPF application.
I was digging in one of their PDF files and found a parameter you can pass to the msi.

You have to install the application using a command line using a command window run as Admin.

The command line:

```
MSIEXEC /i "[PATH_OF_THE_MSI_FILE]" TEXT_SERVICE_SUPPORT=1
```

For example:

```
MSIEXEC /i "C:\Nuance Software\DNS12\Dragon NaturallySpeaking 12.msi" TEXT_SERVICE_SUPPORT=1
```